# Bash egrep Regex A-Z,a-z,0-9 and plus,minus, space seems not to work

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to match a String which contains A-Z,a-z,0-9 and plus,minus, space.

So, I tried that Regex:

```
 egrep '[^A-Za-z0-9\+\-]\+[[:space:]]\+'
```

Seems to allow everything, when I try it differently:

```
 egrep '[^A-Za-z0-9\+\-\s]'
```

Using \s instead of :space: it returns 0 and the spaces seem not to match the pattern. It seems to has an issue if i got 2 spaces after each other.

Input: gameserver start -console -game garrysmod +maxplayers 14 +map gm_flatgrass

Any idea, why it dosent work? Thanks.

Comment: Provide a minimal example of input & output.

Comment: @sat Ups, here you go: gameserver start -console -game garrysmod +maxplayers 14 +map gm_flatgrass but seems like I missed the _ still not works anyway.

Comment: Fixed it by myself, needed some little break and a new focus. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This RegEx seems to work fine:

```
egrep '[^A-Za-z0-9\_\+\-\s]+$'
```

Comment: `echo a b | egrep  '[^A-Za-z0-9\_\+\-\s]+$'` doesn't match. Is that "fine"? Changing `\s` to `[:space:]` returns `grep: Invalid range end`.

Comment: Well I tested on my site multiple times and it seems to work fine, everything else gets blocked off and it only matches the pattern.

Comment: It should be `egrep '[^A-Za-z0-9 _+-]+$'` or  `egrep '[^A-Za-z0-9[:space:]_+-]+$'`. Or, if `\s` is supported, `egrep '[^A-Za-z0-9\s_+-]+$'`